# How cheked IsAuthenticated user?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

How check role user?
I use silverligth bisnes aplication

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelControlsAdmin" >
see admin
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelControlsUser" >
see user
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelControlsAdminUser" >
see admin and user
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be some webcontext.current.user
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: This not helped me. I need check in XAML

Comment: You need to better specify your question... You can store userinformation in a property in your code behind, then bind a label to this property.